# Why do methods from Enumerable return an Enumerator?

Tags: ruby, iterator, enumeration, enumerable

Many methods from Ruby's `Enumerable` will return an `Enumerator` if you don't pass a block.

Example:

```
array = [1,2,3]
array.each.class
# => Enumerator
array.each { |n| n+10 }.class
# => Array
```

What is the reason for this? Why wouldn't they just return `nil` or something else signaling that no block was given.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "method couldn't `each` itself".

Comment: Thanks. I've cleaned up the description.

Answer (score 4):

### Enumerators Give You Control Over Iteration

Among other things, Enumerators give you control over *when* you iterate over an object. Sometimes you don't need the iteration to happen *now*, so you store the Enumerator for later use rather than immediately passing the results to a block. Other times, you may want finer-grained control over the iteration process itself.

One of the most useful (and underused) methods is [Enumerable#lazy](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy). Rather than reifying a million integers from a range all at once, you can grab one at a time when you need it. For example:

```
enum = (1..1_000_000).lazy
enum.next #=> 1
enum.next #=> 2
enum.peek #=> 3
enum.next #=> 3
```

This has obvious performance implications. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Good answer. Another benefit is that enumerators can be passed to methods as arguments to be acted upon using `next`, `peek`, etc., without knowing what the enumerator is (e.g., `arr.select` or `arr.reject`). Enumerators are sometimes also useful to simplify awkward code. For example, if you want a value to alternate between `true` and `false`, you can simply write `v = [true,false].cycle`, then `v.next => true; v.next => false; v.next => true...`.